# How to read a growing file from a linux machine using c#

Tags: c#, linux, file, ftp

I have a c# application which needs to read a log file that is generated by a Linux application and it continuously keeps growing. I got a reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx but  i was not able to find a way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ftp you can send a `ftp-webrequest` with `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp` to the server. Also you can run your .Net code with `mono` on the Linux machine. try using the `System.IO.File` classes methods `GetLastWriteTime(file)` and `GetLastAccessTime(file)`. With mono on the linux machine this .Net code should work.

Answer (score 0):

try using SSH.Net from:
https://sshnet.codeplex.com/
then you will be able to use SSH/SCP/SFTP commands to get what you
need from your linux machine

Comment: well how to integrate ssh.net in visual studio 2010?

Comment: you can add it as project to your solution and then reference it in your project. it's a dot.net wrapper for ssh/scp and more